# Data is not loading when downloaded with gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a Python program that, among other things, download a Google Sheet using the official apis and gspread:

```
def download_gs_sheet(data_path_: str, filename: str, s_name: str, doc_id: str =__doc_id_horarios) -> None:
    """ Función para descargar hoja de cálculo desde Google Sheets

    :param data_path_: La ruta donde se guardará el archivo.
    :param filename: el nombre del archivo a guardar.
    :param s_name: La pestaña/hoja a descargar del documento.
    :param doc_id: El identificador del documento.
    """
    credential = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'credentials', "service_account.json")
    gc = gspread.service_account(credential)
    spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key(doc_id)
    worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(s_name)
    rows = worksheet.get_values()

    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    print(df)
    filename = os.path.join(data_path_, filename)
    df.to_excel(filename)
```

The problem is that the data isn't loading correctly, and when the file is open, several "Loading" fields appear ("Cargando...", in Spanish):
[image: The problem is that the content is not showed, instead "Cargando..." field are displayed.]

I have no problem with the credentials or downloading other files, just this one.

The problematic document is a bit complex, even when viewed from the browser it takes several seconds to display the content correctly.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

```
type here
```

I also tried with pydrive2 and the same problem arises.

Comment: The sheet use several "formulas" of the type:  
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PlG....aA/edit#gid=189019781";CONCATENAR("David!";A1;"6")) to collect the data from other pages (from the same sheet)

Comment: That chain of formulas may be at fault. You seem to be retrieving all the data to convert into a dataframe to then convert to Excel. You could try to skip the middleman and use the [export()](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/spreadsheet.html#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.export) function in gspread to have the Google API convert it to Excel directly.